# jQuery: find all the parents up to a specific parent

Tags: jquery

Is there a built in function in jQuery that would allow me to get all the parents up to a parent with specific Id? I have a deeply nested unordered list, and if I have a reference to one of the "li" I need to find all parent "li" up to a root "ul".  If I use parents() it gives me all parents up to a root of document. One way would be just to write recursive function and check for id of the parent, but if there is something built in I would rather use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parents Until](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) should work for that.  I think you need jQuery 1.4 to use it though.

Comment: Cool, I'll have to upgrade to 1.4

Comment: Yeah, it definitely is version 1.4 only. Upgrading (hopefully) shouldn't be a big problem though.

Answer (score 2):

$('li').closest('ul')

Comment: He wants all the parents, not just the top most.