# How can I find a parent with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: find all the parents up to a specific parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112822/jquery-find-all-the-parents-up-to-a-specific-parent)

I have the following:

```
<div class="modal-window block-border">
    <ul class="action-tabs right">
        <li><a title="Close window" href="#"><img width="16" height="16" src="images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="block-content no-title">
        <div style="min-width: 200px; min-height: 40px; width: 300px; height: 221px;" class="modal-content modal-scroll">
            <h1>Admin</h1>
            <div class="block-header">
                Please login
            </div>
            <form novalidate="novalidate" action="/MyAccount/Access/JsonLogin" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="dialogSuccess()" data-ajax-update="#update-message" name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post">
```

I have a reference to the form which is $(this). Given this reference how can I find a reference to the class with the top most div called "modal-window" ?

Comment: hiya using `.parent` api http://api.jquery.com/parent/ hope this helps, :) cheerios!

Comment: Try googling `parent jquery` and your first hit will give your the above link.

Comment: It's also the **wrong method** to use, given that the `.modal-window` element is **not** the immediate-parent of the `form` element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you might not be sure of exactly how far the target element is from the current element, and assuming you only want to find *one* target element:

```
$(this).closest('.modal-window');
```

- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects the immediate-parent element of `$(this)`, returns a jQuery object of one, or none.
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) selects *all* matching ancestor elements of `$(this)`, returns a jQuery object of one, none or many.
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selects the *first* element matching the selector in the DOM 'tree' above the `$(this)`, returns a jQuery object of one, or none.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.parents()` function, and pass it a selector to get the parents matching it, this means that if the specified selector is used multiple times by parents it will return all matching parents.

```
$(this).parents('.modal-window');
```

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: No; `parents()` can create a jQuery object of none, one or many. It searches all the way up the DOM tree to the `html` element. You linked to the API, you should re-read: "...(...and on up the DOM tree all the way to the `<html>` element). Since we do not supply a selector expression, all of the ancestors are part of the returned jQuery object. If we had supplied one, only the matching items among these would be included."

Comment: @DavidThomas Updated & +1 to you :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents('.modal-window');
```

It is parents not parent because you want ancestor not immediate parent.

See http://api.jquery.com/parent/ and http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.parent()` function from [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).